# Can i use asp.net membership with owin and oauth provider?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership

I have started to create ASP.NET membership for learning basis but i found new ASP.NET Identity. Some people suggested that latter is advanced than ASP.NET membership and ASP.NET simple membership.

I have [read the comparison from this source](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/identity-membership-simplemembership.aspx). But still i have some questions because i some things are still unclear to me.

1. Can i use owin and oauth with ASP.NET membership and simple membership?
2. how i can authenticate web api with ASP.NET membership and simple membership?
3. Can i  customize tables for profile, user and role in ASP.NET Identity?

Please suggest. If any one can suggest me a good reference for authorization and authentication of web API and ASP.NET Identity configuration, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Identity** is now a mature technology and it's complex enough to accommodate all your requirements.

More than so, there is even a better solution, it's called **ASP.NET Identity Server** and comes with couple things extra:

- Can be used with Identity
- Implements SSO (Single Sign-On)
- Can be used with Entity Framework
- It's a self host product

So to answer you're questions:

1. No, you cannot use both Identity and Simple Membership.
2. Using ASP.NET Identity Server, via a token.
3. You can customize the tables to meet you requirements.

Here is the [official documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) for the Identity Server.